# Half Circle Overlay in Background on the Bottom of Page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on adding a fix half circle overlay in background on the bottom of page.

**Structure of all Pages in App (all pages are responsive)**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        
        // Top Bar => Icons e.t.c
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
        </StackLayout>

        // Center => Content
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        </StackLayout>

        // End => Button
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                         VerticalOptions="End">
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Now, I wanted to add an Half Circle Overlay, but I couldn't do that by code, so, I used the Image for this half circle overlay.

I wanted to add it in last `StackLayout`, but can't put `RelativeLayout` in `StackLayout`. So, I remove the last `StackLayout` and pasted the `RelativeLayout` code instead.

```
<RelativeLayout
    HorizontalOptions="End">
    <Image
        Source="drawable/background_halfcircle.png"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
    <Grid
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">

        <Button
            Text="Button"
            Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
    </Grid>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the problem is that it pushed all the code in `Start` & `Center` `StackLayout` to the top (stretched it, looking terrible).

How could I add this Half Circle Overlay in the bottom of every page and the above `StackLayout` aren't get effected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to overlay using a one-row Grid:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Grid Row/Column default to 0. -->
        <StackLayout>
            ... everything that isn't in the overlay ...
        </StackLayout>
        <!-- Grid Row/Column default to 0; so overlaid on StackLayout -->
        <RelativeLayout ...
            ...
        </RelativeLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In fact, I never use RelativeLayout. Can do everything you want using Grid rows and columns.

- Overlay by specifying same row/column.
- Proportions using row/column specifiers, e.g. "2*", "3*'.
- stack-like layouts using "Auto" height or width. (I do use StackLayout when convenient; just mentioning that Grid can incorporate stack-like areas.)

On paper, sketch desired layout. Draw vertical and horizontal lines to separate the areas. Then can determine how to put into a grid. For example, one area might span two columns.

Comment: Thanks for this information, i replaced `RelativeLayout` with `Grid`.. I posted the Updated code above, have a look.. now, two things. 1) I want to decrease the height of last stacklayout, but can't. 2) if the above stacklayout content is too long, this half circle come on the top of it (hide the below content), what should I do?

Comment: @Stavrogin - I don't understand (2). I thought you wanted to OVERLAY one on top of the other. If you aren't overlaying, then why were you using RelativeLayout in the first place? Why not just "stacklayout" everything? Anyway, you use Grid.Row and RowDefinitions to control how stuff is laid out in grid. As for height of a stacklayout, this is either done via HeightRequest property of StackLayout, or if it is contained in a Grid, by manipulating the RowDefinition for the Row it is in. Please read grid docs and examples. Attempt to fix it. If fix doesn't work, post code you tried.

Comment: yes, I wanted Overlay, but my bad, I wanted something else, and asked something else.. anyways, thanks for your comment, it solved the problem.. thanks again :)